# Adding publicPath to Storybook React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

We have our Storybook React project in a subpath (http://example.com/storybook) but the production version is looking for assets at the top level (http://example.com/font.woff).

I was reading that you could add a publicPath property or add an override on `__webpack_public_path__` but I can't see where to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Storybook. Please check the options for build command line. I solved my problem using this link, specially

```
build-storybook --static-dir storybook
```

https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/cli-options/

Comment: how did you serve your static build?

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you. But if you mean remotely like, hosting on a clouding, I did like a normal static website.

Comment: This sorted my problem, thanks

Comment: This answer is **DEPRECATED**. Add `staticDirs: ['../storybook'],` in your `.storybook/main.js`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vite to build storybook, instead of `publicPath` I had to set `config.base` in `main.js`, like so:

```
export default {
  ...
  viteFinal: (config) => {
    config.base = '/storybook-subdir/';
    ...
    return config
  }
};
```

You can also define a variable and use a dynamic value, for example

```
config.base = process.env.PUBLIC_DIR || config.base;
```

Finally build storybook

```
PUBLIC_DIR=/storybook-subdir/ build-storybook
```